# System of equations. How to put next to a variable without a constant the number 1 (using gsub or stringr functions)

Tags: r

How can I turn a string like for example this (the number of equations and variables is not important):

```
my_string<-"−x+2y+z=−1; x−3y−2z=−1; 3x−y+z=4"
```

into this string:

```
my_string<-"−1x+2y+1z=−1; 1x−3y−2z=−1; 3x−1y+1z=4"
```

It means automatically put next to a variable [a-z] without a constant the number 1. 
I've tried with gsub and stringr functions but didn't manage to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a simple regex,

```
gsub('(^|[[:punct:]]|\\s)([a-z])', '\\11\\2', my_string)
#[1] "-1x+2y+1z=-1; 1x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-1y+1z=4"
```

Comment: Or `gsub("([[:punct:] ])([a-z])", "\\11\\2", my_string)`

Comment: or `gsub('(^|\\W)([a-z])', '\\11\\2', my_string)`